# I need help moving the post /page title of my pages/posts BELOW my featured image, or hide it altogether

Tags: hide, posts, page-title

Currently, my title overlays my cover image on my pages and posts. I do not like this and want it either hidden or removed. I've tried plugins and they don't work. What code can I use to do this? I have a child theme.

My Site with example of this: https://intentionaldetours.com/example-laos-article/

Plugins that didn't work and messed up my menu. I just want this text deleted on the display, I need it to show up in other areas of the site

Don't have any

Titles either not displaying at all on pages, and for post below the featured image

Answer (score 0):

Do you want remove the text "Example Laos Article 2 months ago"? Is it?

If so, you can add some CSS code to hide it.

Something like:

```
.entry-header {
   display: none;
}
```